# Nodejs Express - Post Request with JSON file

Tags: node.js

This is my code:

```
var fs = require('fs');

fs.readFile('./public/samp.json', "utf8", function readFile(err, data) {
  if(err) {
    throw err;
  }
  else {
    app.post('/api/process', function(data, res) {
      sessCntrlr.procedure(pool, res, req);
      console.log(res);
    });
  }
});
```

My goal here is to get the information from a json file ('./public/samp.json') and use that to post request to the API. I know and understand that it should be the client that should be sending requests, but I'm trying to figure out if it is possible to post a request via json file.

Any ideas? My code above doesn't work at all, except to the part where I get the data using fs.readFile.

Comment: `app.post` is only adding a handler to `/api/post` which may be called by the client and what do you mean exactly by doesn't work at all?

Comment: @SureshPrajapati - When I try to console.log the supposed result, i get nothing. That said, I dont think it even proceeds after the app.post

Comment: @SureshPrajapati - so how do I send the data that I got from the readFile to the supposed API function if app.post wont work this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not create API inside the callback. If you want to use create the different function and used for file and API both.

```
var fs = require('fs');

var process = (pool, res, req) => {
    /* Do something */
    sessCntrlr.procedure(pool, res, req);
}


app.post('/api/process', function (req, res) {
    /* Do something and get params for process */
    process(pool, res, req);
});


fs.readFile('./public/samp.json', "utf8", function readFile(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    } else {
        /* Do something and get params for process */
        process(pool, res, req);
    }
});
```

Comment: Noted. But question still remains on how to use the data (the response from readFile) as a request to the API (/api/process)?

Comment: Now the process is a different function you can pass whatever you want.

Comment: This is not a 100% clean solution as I had to fix some errors, though answers in this site should not always be spoonfeeding. Nevertheless, this definitely worked! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First, `app.post('/api/process',function(){})` is a handler on the server side to handle the incoming `POST` request.

To make `POST` call on the server side node app, you can use [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) npm.

```
'use strict';

let fs = require('fs');
let request = require('request');

let jsonData = fs.readFileSync('./public/samp.json', 'utf8');

request({
  method: 'POST',
  url: '/api/process',
  body: jsonData, //information from json
  headers: {
    'User-Agent': 'Request-Promise'
  },
  json: true
}, function (error, response, body) {
  if (error) {
    console.log('error', error);
  }

  console.log('body', body);
  sessCntrlr.procedure(pool, res, req); //your code
});
```